# Do these two variants of polynomials have names? Or has anyone worked out their useful properties?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Here’s a couple more patterns I am seeing in my modeling.  And again my searches for mathematicians who have already worked out their useful properties has not turned up much… so, I thought I’d check here for pointers and/or for the common names these are given:

**Pattern #1:**
$$ 
f(x, a, c) = a x + \frac{c}{x}
$$
which generalizes to:
$$\begin{align}
f(x, a, b, c) &= a x + b + \frac{c}{x} 
\\     &= \frac{a x^2 + b x + c}{x}
\\     &= \frac{quadratic(x, a, b, c)}{x}
\end{align}
$$
so a variant of the univariate quadratic function, but *not* really a second-order polynomial, since in its simplest form it does not have a squared term.

**Pattern #2:**
$$
 f(x, w) = \frac{x}{w} + \frac{w}{x}
$$
which generalizes to:
$$\begin{align}
f(x, w, a, b, c) &= a \frac{x}{w} + b + c \frac{w}{x} 
\\        &= \frac{a x^2 + b x w + c w^2}{x w}
\\        &= \frac{quadratic2(x, w, a, b, c)}{x w}
\end{align}
$$
so a variant of the bivariate quadratic function, but again *not* really a second-order polynomial, since in its simplest form it does not have any squared or second-order terms.

**Questions:**

What has (*or would*) a mathematician named (*name*) any of those four functions?

And have any mathematicians worked out the useful properties of those?

(I don’t want to miss out on the wisdom I can glean from past mathematical analyses, just because I don't know the right search terms. And I don’t want to name those something and have people ask, “Why didn’t you use its proper name, xxx?”)

Comment: Both are very simple cases of [Laurent polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial), though I am not aware of a special name for either.

Comment: Personal opinion.  No special names.  Rational function for more general cases - polynomial divided by polynomial.

Comment: Most of these, as long as you distinguish coefficients from variables, are quadratic forms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form